# How to find the length of $f^{n}(a)$ and $i^{th}$ digit for any n such that length of $f^{n}(a)$ is greater than $i$.

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, combinatorics-on-words, morphism

Suppose $S$ is a finite set of characters, which we will assume is a subset of{a,b,c,d,e,f}.  Then $S^*$ denotes the set of all sequences whose elements are these characters, that is, it is just the set of all strings, also called words, containing only the given set of characters.
A morphism $f$ is a function $f: S → S^*$ that assigns to each character $x∈S$ some word $f(x)∈S^*$.  The morphism $f$ can be extended to all words in $S^∗$ by defining $f(λ) =λ$ and $f(w·x) =f(w)·f(x)$, for all words $w∈S^*$ and characters $x∈S$.  Here $λ$ is the empty word and $(·)$ denotes concatenation. Suppose $f(a)$ also has $a$ as the first character.  Then consider the sequence of words $a,f(a),...,fn(a),...,$  where $f^0(a) = a $ and $f^n(a)=f(f^{n−1}(a))$.   It  can  be  seen  that $f^{n−1}(a)$ is a prefix of $f^n(a)$ for all $n≥1$, and as $n→∞$ this sequence approaches a fixed, possibly infinite, word called its limit.

> How to find the length of $f^{n}(a)$ and $i^{th}$ digit for any n such that length of $f^{n}(a)$ is greater than $i$.

Comment: It would be better to use a different variable for the length of the string and the number of iterations of the function. Maybe the length should be $L$.  What do the Fibonacci numbers have to do with this?

Comment: I rolled back to the initial question about the length, to which Ross Millikan gave an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will let $S=\{a,b,c\}$.  You can make a matrix that shows what characters each character becomes.  Each word corresponds to a column vector that shows the number of $a$s in the first entry, $b$s in the second and $c$s in the third.  The matrix will take the character counts of a word $w$ and give the character counts of $f(w)$.  The length of a word is then the sum of the entries in the column vector.  The columns correspond to the input characters and each row is the number of a given output character generated by each input character.

As an example, let $f(a)=ab, f(b)=bcca, f(c)=cbc$  Then the matrix is
$$\begin {bmatrix} 1&1&0\\1&1&1\\0&2&2 \end {bmatrix}$$
where the first column tells us that each $a$ in a word becomes one $a$ and one $b$ (in some order-we are not keeping track of that).  Your starting word has the vector
$$\begin {bmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end {bmatrix}$$ and each application of $f$ corresponds on one multiplication by the matrix.  To get the length of the $n^{th}$ iterate of $f$, multiply your starting vector by the $n^{th}$ power of the matrix and sum the components.

You can get an asymptotic growth rate for the length by finding the eigenvalues of the matrix and taking the largest.  In the example, the [largest eigenvalue](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors%7B%7B1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C2%2C2%7D%7D) is about $3.17$ corresponding to the eigenvector $\begin {bmatrix} 0.270\\0.585\\1 \end {bmatrix}$  The length will multiply by about $3.17$ each iteration and the proportion of letters will be as shown in the eigenvector.

For my example, $f(a)=ab, f^2(a)=abbcca, f^3(a)=abbccabccacbccbcab$ and so on.

Comment: This process does not calculate the $i^{th}$ element.  The question you asked was just about the length of the string, so that is all it pays attention to.  The last paragraph is standard in linear algebra, where you often find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix.  If you haven't studied it, it will be described in those texts.

Comment: I don't have an approach except computation.  It would not be hard to write a program that implements $f(w)$ and iterate it.  The nice thing about computing length is you can forget about the order of the letters and just look at how many there are of each.

Comment: I put the first three iterates into the answer.  You just take the output of one stage as the input to the next, so string together the values of $f(a), f(b), f(c)$ based on the characters you have.  You defined that $f(ab)=f(a)\cdot f(b)$ and so on.

Comment: can you please update your answer.

Comment: Unless there is something special about $f$, like all the images have the same length, I don't think there is anything better than computation as in my last paragraph.  If all the $f(x)$ are longer than $x$, or at least $f(a)$ is longer and all the rest are at least the same length, once you get to length $i$ it will never change.

Comment: for $i$ if we go backward then computation is easy right?

Comment: It's not easy if the $f(x)$ have different lengths because you don't know where it came from.  It depends on what characters are part of $x$.  If they all have the same length you know were it came from by a simple integer division.  If $f(a)=ab$ and $f(b)=bab$ and you see a $b$ you can't know where it came from so you can't step back to the start easily.

Comment: Okay, is it easy to calculate if f have some property like 1. $f(a)=ab$ and $f(b)=a$ and 2. $f(a)=ab$ and $f(b)=ba$. for this special can you explain because your deleted answer have similar property.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  Some functions will allow you to calculate where a letter comes from easily.  Some will not.  If all the function values have the same length it is easy, but other functions can have properties that make it easy as well.  I don't think there is a good way to characterize those.